# HashMap List Is Null In ViewModel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, mvvm

I am building a chat app, and I am retrieving last chats with unread messages.

I am using firebase as my database and MVVM pattern.

So the problem is that I have to run 3 firebase requests in order to get HashMap with contact name and last unseen messages.

I am running the first function `"getUsersChatList"` that is located in the repository.
In that function I call the second function `"getUsersLastChat(arrayList)"` and I am passing the result of the last function.

From `"getUsersLastChat(arrayList)"` I call the last function `"searchNumberOfMessages(user)"` and I am passing the result of the previous function.

`"searchNumberOfMessages"` result is a List of HashMap with the contact name and the unread messages.

I declared at the top of my repository a MutableLiveData that stores the list of hashMap and I created a function to observe its changes,however,its not getting called because the value is not updated and I don't know why.

Here is what I have done:

**Repository:**

**Top repository:**

```
var newMessages = MutableLiveData<List<HashMap<String, Any?>>>()
```

**getUsersChatList:**

```
fun getUsersChatList(){

        val arrayList = ArrayList<ChatList>()

        chatListRef.child(currentUser!!.uid).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (snapshot2 in snapshot.children) {

                    val singleListItem = snapshot2.getValue(ChatList::class.java)

                    if (singleListItem != null) {
                        arrayList.add(singleListItem)
                    }

                }

                getUsersLastChat(arrayList)


            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })

    }
```

**getUsersLastChat:**

```
private fun getUsersLastChat(arrayList: ArrayList<ChatList>){

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (snapshot2 in snapshot.children){

                    val user = snapshot2.getValue(User::class.java)

                    for (eachChatList in arrayList)
                    {

                        if (user!!.uid.equals(eachChatList.id))
                        {
                            searchNumberOfMessages(user)
                        }

                    }

                }


            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })

    }
```

**This is where the problem,searchNumberOfMessages:**

```
fun searchNumberOfMessages(user: User) : MutableLiveData<List<HashMap<String, Any?>>> {

        val messageArray = ArrayList<String?>()

        val hashMapArray = ArrayList<HashMap<String, Any?>>()
        val hasMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()

        chatRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                for (snapshot2 in snapshot.children) {

                    val chat = snapshot2.getValue(Message::class.java)

                    if (chat!!.receiver.equals(currentUser!!.uid) && chat.sender.equals(
                            user.uid)) {

                        if (chat.seen == false){
                            messageArray.add(chat.message)
                        }

                    }

                }


                hasMap["Sender"] = user.userName
                hasMap["Messages"] = messageArray.size


                hashMapArray.add(hasMap)

                newMessages.value = hashMapArray

                Log.e("newMessages", "newMessages: ${newMessages.value}") // Getting the current Values with No Problem


            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })

        Log.e("newMessages2", "newMessages2: ${newMessages.value}") // Getting null on the same value and pass the null object to the viewModel

        return newMessages
    }
```

**In the viewModel:**

```
fun getUsersChatList(): MutableLiveData<List<HashMap<String, Any?>>> {
    mainRepository.getUsersChatList()
    return mainRepository.newMessages
}
```

**And in the activity:**

```
chatsListFragmentViewModel.getUsersChatList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,object : Observer<List<HashMap<String, Any?>>?> {
            override fun onChanged(t: List<HashMap<String, Any?>>?) {

                Log.e("userMessagesHashMap","userMessagesHashMap ${t}")

            }
        })
```

**This is the result in logcat:**

```
2022-01-20 04:13:31.604 13145-13145/com.dapps.misronim E/newMessages2: newMessages2: null
2022-01-20 04:13:31.610 13145-13145/com.dapps.misronim E/newMessages2: newMessages2: null
2022-01-20 04:13:31.779 13145-16093/com.dapps.misronim D/FA: Application going to the background
2022-01-20 04:13:31.859 13145-13145/com.dapps.misronim E/newMessages: newMessages: [{Sender=Mario, Messages=4}]
2022-01-20 04:13:31.873 13145-13145/com.dapps.misronim E/newMessages: newMessages: [{Sender=Dj, Messages=2}]
2022-01-20 04:13:31.886 13145-13145/com.dapps.misronim E/newMessages: newMessages: [{Sender=Jfioo32856, Messages=0}]
```

**Thank you very much for your time and help,I really appreciate it !**

Comment: I think that this article, [How to optimize Firebase Realtime Database calls to improve performance?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-optimize-firebase-realtime-database-calls-to-improve-performance-cc63dad374d5) will help achieve what you want when using the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Log.e("newMessages2", "newMessages2: ${newMessages.value}")

        return newMessages
    }`
```

This code will return a null value because ondataChanged is not done yet. which means that you cannot return anything. Try observing newMessages instead

```
//in your viewModel
val messages = mainRepository.newMessages

fun getUsersChatList(){
 mainRepository.getUserChatList()
}
//in your fragment
chatsListFragmentViewModel.getUserChatList()
chatsListFragmentViewModel.messages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,object : 
Observer<List<HashMap<String, Any?>>?> {
        override fun onChanged(t: List<HashMap<String, Any?>>?) {

            Log.e("userMessagesHashMap","userMessagesHashMap ${t}")

        }
    })
```